# Get arrays between two values of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on an array and I would like to get all the arrays between two values of an array eg

```
$fields = array(
 'a' => array(
  'name' => 'username',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'b' => array(
  'name' => 'birthday',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'c' => array(
  'name' => 'address',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'd' => array(
  'name' => 'password',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
);
```

So that given `username` and `password` I want to get the following

```
 'b' => array(
  'name' => 'birthday',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'c' => array(
  'name' => 'address',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
```

Simply because it comes after the array with the value of username and before the array with value of password

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem on your own?

Comment: Are you trying to get 'b' and 'c' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop with two condition like below

```
$start = "username";
$end = "password";
$new = array();
$flag = false;
foreach($fields as $key=>$value){
  if($value["name"] == $start){
    $flag = true;
    continue;
  }
  if($value["name"] == $end){
    break;;
  }
  if($flag){
    $new[$key] = $value;
  }
}
print_r($new);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/879235

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `name` values into an array, search that and slice using the search result positions:

```
$names  = array_column($fields, 'name');
$result = array_slice($fields, $i=array_search('username', $names)+1,
                                  array_search('password', $names)-$i);
```

Comment: Whoops, sorry. You are right. You've got my vote for an elegant solution

Comment: But since the 3rd parameter of `array_slice` is a length and not an index, you should update your answer for something like this:

`$names  = array_column($fields, 'name');
$offset = array_search('username', $names);
$result = array_slice($fields, $offset+1,
    array_search('password', $names)-$offset-1);

print_r($result);` That way the code will work also if "username" is not in the 1st cell.

Comment: Sure. try running this code on this array: `$fields = array(
  '0' => array(
  'name' => 'other',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'a' => array(
  'name' => 'username',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'b' => array(
  'name' => 'birthday',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'c' => array(
  'name' => 'address',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'd' => array(
  'name' => 'password',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
);`

Comment: @HtmHell So yes, if you deviate from OPs array structure, however since it was simple I edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getArraysBetweenNames($name1, $name2, $array)
{
    $return = [];
    $foundName1 = false;

    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($foundName1) {
            if ($item["name"] == $name2)
                break;

            $return[$key] = $item;
        } elseif ($item["name"] == $name1) {
            $foundName1 = true;
        }

    }

    return $return;
}

print_r(getArraysBetweenNames("username", "password", $fields));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$fields = array(
 'a' => array(
  'name' => 'username',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'b' => array(
  'name' => 'birthday',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'c' => array(
  'name' => 'address',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
 'd' => array(
  'name' => 'password',
  'type' => 'text',
  ),
);
```

if you want b,c array from the fields you just

```
echo $fields[b][name];
echo $fields[b][type]; 
echo $fields[c][name];
echo $fields[c][type];
```

Comment: This doesn't help answer the question, and although it does run, you really meant to quote `"b"`, `"c"`, `"name"`, and `"type"`. (The current code will emit warnings for each of those undefined constants.)